# Why is program not compiling?

Tags: c++

Please help me find out whats wrong why my devcpp doesnt compile my program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Hello There please input A number" << endl;
int number;
  cin >> number;
  if( number >= 2 && number <= 2 )
   {
     cout << "You have input the wrong number haha" << endl;
  } 
  else
  {
    cout << "Wow how'd you guessed it?" << endl;
 }

 system("PAUSE>NUL");
 return 23;
}
```

Comment: You want `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`. Not sure if that's it. Posting the compiler error(s) you get is helpful.

Comment: How do you try to compile this? What happens when you try? Is there a specific error message printed?

Comment: The compiler tells you why it doesn't compile.

Comment: Are you not getting any sort of compiler errors? You should get some reason(s) displayed as to what could be the issue.

Comment: `if( number >= 2 && number <= 2 )` How about `if (number == 2)`? That also seems to be the opposite logic from your output.

Comment: `if( number >= 2 && number <= 2 )` made me lol

Comment: it says: [General Error] Too many messages; abort. There must be something terribly wrong with your code. Please fix it

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean: `if(number!= 0 && number!=1 && number!=3 && number!=4.....`

Comment: And _why_ are you returning `23` of all numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Taking that and compiling it gives me the simple error:

```
fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
```

This is self-explanatory. The reason is that `<iostream>` doesn't have an extension, or a  `.h` equivalent. Change the line to:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Proof that it compiles (not including the following points, but removing things irrelevant to ideone): http://ideone.com/WIDjR

Aside from that:

- You don't need `windows.h`. `system` is part of `cstdlib`.
- `using namespace std;` often does more bad than good. It's recommended to stick to `std::cout` etc. Inside `main` isn't the worst place it could be, but nonetheless, not a great habit to get into.
- `if( number >= 2 && number <= 2 )` is a logic error, both in writing and execution. The simpler form would be `if (number == 2)`, but the correct form, based on your output, would be `if (number != 2)`, lest every number other than 2 is the right guess.
- `system ("PAUSE")` is bad. You don't know if `pause.exe` will do that, or if it will even exist. Someone could have a `pause.exe` that formats their hard drive, and you'd be to blame for executing it. Use a form of `cin.get()`, or, if your compiler implements it to clear the input buffer, `cin.sync(); cin.get();` for consistent behaviour. Beware that `cin.sync()`'s behaviour is not guaranteed.
- Your program should be returning 0 from normal exit. Anything else is taken to mean an error occurred. `return 0;` in main is implicit if you don't specify a return value.

Comment: still many errors, many errors, please post answer that works, expert

Comment: @sokuschan, I added in the rest of what I had to say. The reason it wouldn't compile (which was your whole question) was fixed with the first post.